# Does the weight of a bar differ when weighed horizontally from vertically?

Tags: physics

There is a cylindrical bar of length 1 meter just for example. What will be the weight of the bar when weighed horizontally vs vertically? Will it be same or different? What is the reason? Is it because the weight is nothing but force which differs because of weight distributed around center of mass?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about physics instead of programming / coding / programming tools / software algorithms.

Comment: Apologies for posting the question here. Will I be able to move this to Physics.StackExchange?

Answer (score -1):

The weight would be the same, the observation of it does not affect its weight.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer, No. But... Depends on the weighing apparatus, really.

In our place, when I was a kid, me and my cousin actually fold old, rusty metal sheets(those thin metal panels used for roofing) to make it more heavier when we sell it to the junk shop. Even works with just trying to compress metal bars, folding them in to be smaller. Technically (or in reality) it still weighs the same when you lift them up but in my case, they were using this old balance scale where we can actually cheat by doing so.  I believe it has something to do with [Moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(physics)). If they were using something like a hanging scale then the position/volume/surface-area of the object being weighed wouldn't matter (given that the object is not swinging).

Btw, why are you posting this question in stackoverflow?